# Why am I getting History, Location, Match, Static as an object when passing in an argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am passing in an Object of a defined interface in Typescript but the object is different when opened in new page.

```
interface Post  {
  created_at: string;
  description: string;
  excerpt: string;
  html: string;
  title: string;
  feature_image: string;
  slug: string;
}

export default function FeaturedPost( test: Post ) {


  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <CardActionArea component="a" href={"/post/write"}>
        <Route path="/blog/write" />  
          <div onClick={() =>  <Link to="/post/write">  render={() => {  return <MakePost {...test} />   }}  </Link>  }>
```

Here test is an object that has the values {history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined}

When I was expecting a different set of params. Here is the callee.

```
  return (
<div className="App">
  <CssBaseline />
  <Container maxWidth="xl">
    <Header title="Blog"  />
    <main>        
      <MainFeaturedPost post={mainFeaturedPost} />
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        {test.map((post) => (
          <FeaturedPost  {...post} />
```

Comment: Where are you expecting a different set a params? Please clarify your question/issue. It also looks like you are trying to return JSX from a click hander (*but returned to what?*), and then also mixing a `Link` component with a `Route` component. It's unclear what you want the code to do.

Comment: I am trying to pass the value "test" into MakePost where I will use it. Test is of type post Interface. The reason I used a link and route is because I want to render MakePost on click of the card element.

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't return JSX to be rendered from a click handler, so if a `MakePost` component is being rendered it is one from somewhere else, which very likely explains why it's receiving different props. From what I can tell you are rendering a `MakePost` component via a `Route` and it's just receiving the route props. If you are trying to send data to a component then you need to use route state sent from the `Link` and received/accessed via the `location` prop.

Comment: So how would you call <MakePost/> from an onlick button whilst also passing in params?

Comment: You don't. You can't. If you want to pass additional props you do that where the component is being rendered by a `Route`. If you want to pass data when navigating to *that* route then use route state. See [Link to object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object).